# How do I change this script to OnMouseOver?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this script that needs to be changes to OnMouseOver, currently it functions when you click but I need it to function when the mouse cursor goes over a div. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<script> 

// execute your scripts when the DOM is ready. this is a good habit
$(function() {

    // assign a click event to the exposed element, using normal jQuery coding
    $("#menuwrapper").mouseOver(function() {

        // perform exposing for the clicked element
        $(this).expose();

    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's mouseover (all lowercase), not mouseOver.

http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Comment: well I feel pretty dumb now lol thanks Geon, I sat here for a while wondering why it wasn't working